# Swift Vapor 4 Leaf Image not displayed in view on run

Tags: swift, image, vapor, leaf

I am doing my first steps in vapor 4 using leaf as view renderer. In my data i am pasting image urls but when I run the page the browser does not show them. The browser always shows the value of the "alt" tag.
So I tried to build a static leaf page which only shows an image from the internet but this is also not displaying the image. I can not figure out why. Do I have to set somewhere that the running test Webserver should render images? I am using macOS Big Sur 11.0.1

Here is my leaf code (it's simple html code but does not display the image)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Image Test</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg">
        <img scr="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" alt="test image" width="500" height="600">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try src instead of scr in your img tag!!!

Comment: OMG!! How can i give you 100 points for this? I did many tests and the error is a spelling mistake! Thank you so much! Please write this as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nick said it was a speeling mistake .

I wrote „scr“, but it must be „src“
Correct:

```
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg" alt="test image" width="500" height="600">
```